# Selenium with TorBrowser

Tags: java, selenium

**when i use this code, tor could not started. What is the problem in this code?**

```
String torPath = "C:\\Users\\kaptan\\Desktop\\Browser\\firefox.exe";
    String profilePath = "C:\\Users\\kaptan\\Desktop\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default";
```

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\Users\kaptan\Desktop\geckodriver.exe");

```
    File torProfileDir = new File(profilePath);
    FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torPath));
    FirefoxProfile torProfile = new FirefoxProfile(torProfileDir);
    torProfile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
    torProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    torProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
    torProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setProfile(torProfile);
    options.setBinary(binary);
    options.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options);


    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Anyone?........